# What is Web services in simple terms

Tags: web-services

I am little bit confused about what really a web service is. You say Amazone web services,etc like that, they offer information. So what is the requirement to be a web url to be a web service ? Let's say I am not much familiar with web development, how could you explain it to me ? But I can get it if you point some ways.
And also little about SOAP and REST basically for someone really new

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**What is a web service**

It is many things. In programming, in generally refers to a web page, that can be called from an application (be it another web page, or desktop app), and the caller will pass in data to it, or receive data from it.

In this sense, it's basically like a 'method' or 'function' in a normal programming language; except you're calling it over the internet.

**SOAP**

A message format. As discussed above, a web service is a basically a 'method' or 'function'. SOAP is the 'instructions' and 'data' to this method. It will outline data types, and possibly a bunch of data as well. It is an XML format.

**REST**

REST is the means of implementing an interface to your application *but*, implementing access control, and other such things, specifically with HTTP Response codes. So you will get a 401: Denied (I think that's the right code), if you don't have access. There are other types of response codes that are useful. It also makes use of other HTTP commands like PUT/HEAD/OPTIONS.

Comment: 401 is Unauthorized and 403 is Forbidden - access denied even if you are authenticated..

Answer (score 7):

The [W3C defines a Web Service](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-gloss/#webservice) as *(quoting)* :

> A Web service is a software system
>   designed to support interoperable
>   machine-to-machine interaction over a
>   network. It has an interface described
>   in a machine-processable format
>   (specifically WSDL). Other systems
>   interact with the Web service in a
>   manner prescribed by its description
>   using SOAP-messages, typically
>   conveyed using HTTP with an XML
>   serialization in conjunction with
>   other Web-related standards.

That definition is maybe a bit too restrictive, considering how that term is used nowadays -- I'd probably go with just the first part of that definition, which is quite generalist :

> A Web service is a software system
>   designed to support interoperable
>   machine-to-machine interaction over a
>   network.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) also has some interesting definitions, like :

> In common usage the term refers to
>   clients and servers that communicate
>   over the Hypertext Transfer Protocol
>   (HTTP) protocol used on the Web.

From what I've seen :

- A couple of years ago, when we said "web service", we generally meant "SOAP, WSDL, ..."
- Now, when we say "web service", we often mean "whatever allows to call something on another server, be it SOAP, REST, ..."

Answer (score 2):

A Web-Service can be considered as a set of methods that enables communication amongst applications irrespective of the application's coding language or framework.

http://acharyashri.com/blog/WebServices.html

Answer (score 1):

Think of ***Web services*** as ***remote APIs*** (since they are basically just that). You have a method that you want to implement. Let's suppose the method wasn't built by you and resides somewhere else in the world on equipment that you have no control over—how can you go about providing that remote method what it needs in order to get instantiated?

When you find a Web service that you want to include in your application, you must first figure out how to supply the Web service with the parameters it needs in order for it to work. That need also extends a bit further. Even if you know the parameters and types that are required for instantiation, you also need to understand the types that are passed to your application in return. Without these pieces of information, using Web services would prove rather difficult.

Just as there are standard ways to represent data as well as standard ways to move this data over the Internet using Web services, there is a standard way to get a description of the Web service you are interested in consuming. Web Services Description Language (***WSDL***) is a specification of XML that describes the Web services you are interested in consuming. It's just an interface to describe a web service.