# How to connect and access mssql Database server from Android app?

Tags: android, sql-server, database

I am developing an android application, in that application i simply created login page in that login page i need to load mssql database for login. Please tell the solution and example coding for this one

Comment: MSSQL database installed in server host

Comment: "Please tell the solution and example coding for this one" == "Please code for me"...

Comment: You shouldn't do that, you'd better call an API to login a user, connecting directly to a db from the outside world may lead to huge security problems. if an attacker can get your DB password, he can use it to steal your whole table(s)...

Comment: how can i call api. i dont abt api

Comment: see @Merlí Pérez Escarpenter's answer. But it is trully not an android issue, whatever is your technology, your DB should only be accessed by trusted users, on your private network or on localhost, not by anyone from anywhere.

Comment: Write a WebService on the server side and consume it on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow this is a really complicated!! The apps can't connect directly with server how do websites... Remember the devices it's possible lose internet, then how you connect with you server database? The most important of devices is can work offline, in this moment our app needs a webservice (API) to connect with database from server. Read this posts for more info (that includes code)!

- [What is a webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1353702/3996257)
- [How we do an API?](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) (Server part)
- [How we connect our android device with server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27406857/3996257) (Device part)

Other important post:

- [WebService vs API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808421/api-vs-webservice)
- [Restful vs Other Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285725/restful-vs-other-web-services)

Tell me if I helped you and good programming!