# How to upload a file in android using AsyncTask

Tags: java, php, android, android-asynctask

I am just a beginner at Android so this question might be stupid. PLease help me out of this.

I am working on an App which requires data to be uploaded on the server. The data could be text, image or a video. I tried to use the following link

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

and also

http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

However I ended up being even more confused. How do I send the data into the server using the ASyncTask doinbackgound method.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited for a Google query, rather than a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Even after watching those link you can't able to figure it out then how you assure we can help you out???

Comment: I answered a similar post, you have 3 tutorials and reasons to do with my method. You can read the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30913393/3996257). Tell me if I helped you and good programming!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a REST Client for your networking needs. They allow easy use of Async Http Requests and even easer exception handling.

These are some the most notable REST Clients available out there:

- [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
- [ION](https://github.com/koush/ion)
- [Android-Query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/)